# display data set based on string content using vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I want to display the designated data that is found for a particular code match. I have a data set that will come in model. I want if the data-set, subject property has the first 2-3 characters found in it, to display the corresponding name. Based on the first 3 characters begins with LA_, which is found in the first index, only the first set of content should appear (Name: Library Arts Department: ACSF-LA Identifier: 6774). I know i would need to slice the character off, with string slice, but what if sometimes the name has like LAX_ (SO I want to be sure to check if the subjects have any that match--). So basically to check everything before the first "_"

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  Name:"LA_123_cc",
    todos: [{"Name":"Library Arts","Identifier":"6774","Code":"AACSF-LA","Subjects":["LA_","AEL","APC","GAP","FAC","GLM","GS","MPT","PRO","WNM"]},
   {"Name":"Violin Dance","Identifier":"6169","Code":"Avvv-VA","Subjects":["VA","VL","VPC","AAP","YAC","XLM","GXS","XPT","IRO","CNM"]} 
    
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Name: {{Name}}</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
    Name: {{todo.Name}} <br>
    Department: {{todo.Code}}<br>
    Identifier: {{todo.Identifier}}
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html?redirect=true#Computed-Properties) that uses [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the `todos[]`. The callback to `filter()` receives each array item, and returns `true` if the item should be in the result. In this callback, you can check if each item contains the leading characters (before the underscore) in the search string (`LA` in your example):

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    computedTodos() {
      const searchLetters = this.Name.split('_')[0].split('')   /* get characters of first part of string before underscore */
                                     .filter(x => /\w/.test(x)) /* keep only letters */
      return this.todos.filter(item => {
        /* check if each letter appears in order within the item's name */
        let i = 0
        return searchLetters.every(letter => {
          i = item.Name.indexOf(letter, i)
          return i > -1
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Then update the template to use the computed prop instead of `todos[]`:

```html
<!-- <li v-for="todo in todos"> -->
<li v-for="todo in computedTodos">
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  Name:"LA_123_cc",
    todos: [{"Name":"Library Arts","Identifier":"6774","Code":"AACSF-LA","Subjects":["LA_","AEL","APC","GAP","FAC","GLM","GS","MPT","PRO","WNM"]},
   {"Name":"Violin Dance","Identifier":"6169","Code":"Avvv-VA","Subjects":["VA","VL","VPC","AAP","YAC","XLM","GXS","XPT","IRO","CNM"]} 
    
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    computedTodos() {
      const searchLetters = this.Name.split('_')[0].split('').filter(x => /\w/.test(x))
      return this.todos.filter(item => {
        let i = 0
        return searchLetters.every(letter => {
          i = item.Name.indexOf(letter, i)
          return i > -1
        })
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="Name">
  <h2>Name: {{Name}}</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in computedTodos">
    Name: {{todo.Name}} <br>
    Department: {{todo.Code}}<br>
    Identifier: {{todo.Identifier}}
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```